# Using Tiles templates windows8

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, tiles

I'm trying to use tiles templates(a tile which shows an image and switches to show text)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#TileSquarePeekImageAndText04

The question is: where do I put this XML and how can I call it in XAML?

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868253(v=win.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call it in XAML, you provide it to a [TileUpdater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.aspx) instance, as you can see from the documentation for [TileUpdateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdatemanager.aspx) below.  This simplistic scenario handles a [local notification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/07/windows-8-notifications-local-notifications.aspx) (but there are also [scheduled](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/08/windows-8-notifications-scheduled-notifications.aspx), [periodic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/09/windows-8-notifications-periodic-notifications.aspx), and [push](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/10/15/windows-8-notifications-push-notifications.aspx) notifications you can leverage).

Take a look at the [App tiles and badges](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148) and [Push and periodic notifications](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/push-and-periodic-de225603) samples for guidance.

```
function sendTileTextNotification() {
    var Notifications = Windows.UI.Notifications;

    // Get an XML DOM version of a specific template by using getTemplateContent.
    var tileXml = Notifications.TileUpdateManager.getTemplateContent(Notifications.TileTemplateType.tileWideText03);

    // You will need to look at the template documentation to know how many text fields a particular template has.
    // Get the text attribute for this template and fill it in.
    var tileAttributes = tileXml.getElementsByTagName("text");
    tileAttributes[0].appendChild(tileXml.createTextNode("Hello World!"));

    // Create the notification from the XML.
    var tileNotification = new Notifications.TileNotification(tileXml);

    // Send the notification to the calling app's tile.
    Notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication().update(tileNotification);
}
```